# Event observer doesn't receive event when singleton EJB observes the same event

Tags: jboss7.x, cdi

I have three beans, all with the same method signature:

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
@Startup    //  Eager initialization
@Singleton
public class ApplicationManager
{
    private void onRemoveUserLoginSession(@Observes @Removed UserLoginSession userLoginSession) {
        logger.info("ApplicationManager.onRemoveUserLoginSession");
    }

}

@SessionScoped
public class ManageEventOrWorkflowNotFoundLogConversations
{
    private void onRemoveUserLoginSession(@Observes @Removed UserLoginSession userLoginSession) {
        logger.info("ManageEventOrWorkflowNotFoundLogConversations.onRemoveUserLoginSession");
    }
}

@Dependent
public class ManageEventOrWorkflowNotFoundLogConversation
{
    private void onRemoveUserLoginSession(@Observes @Removed UserLoginSession userLoginSession) {
        logger.info("ManageEventOrWorkflowNotFoundLogConversation.onRemoveUserLoginSession");
    }
}
```

When the event fires only ApplicationManager#onRemoveUserLoginSession's event observer receives the event (e.g. neither of the other two methods receive the event).

When I remove the event observer in the ApplicationManager each of the other two methods receive the event.

```
@Startup    //  Eager initialization
@Singleton
public class ApplicationManager
{
    private void onRemoveUserLoginSession(UserLoginSession userLoginSession) {
        logger.info("ApplicationManager.onRemoveUserLoginSession");
    }

}
```

Here is the bean firing the event:

```
@SessionScoped
public class SessionManager implements UserLoginSession
{
    @Inject @Removed Event<UserLoginSession> sessionRemovedEvent;

    @PreDestroy private void sessionDestroyed() {
        this.sessionRemovedEvent.fire(this);
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?